# strlen giving unexpected outputs C

Tags: c, string

This is my sample code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char a[3] = { 'H', 'E', 'L', 'L', 'O', '\0' };
    printf("Length is %zd ", strlen(a));
}
```

I know this produces the following warning!.

```
test.c:5:26: warning: excess elements in array initializer
 char a[3] = {'H','E','L','L','O','\0'};
```

Now my question is if I specify the size as `a[6]` or anything greater than the actual size my output would be.

for `char a[100] = {'H','E','L','L','O','\0'};`

output:

```
Length is 5
```

for `char a[10] = {'H','E','L','L','O','\0'};`

output:

```
Length is 5
```

for anything equal to or greater than the array size I'm getting correct output.

But when I give anything less than actual size **always** I'm getting 
**6** as output.

for `char a[5] = {'H','E','L','L','O','\0'};` or for `a[4]` or `a[3]` or `a[2]` it's always

`Length is 6`

Though for

```
char a[1] = {'H','E','L','L','O','\0'};
```

it is `Length is 1`.

What is the reason for this?  Any detailed explanations are welcome.

Comment: Undefined behaviour?

Comment: That warning isn't there to make the compiler writers feel better, you know. Did you not wonder why *"excess elements in array initializer"* could be a problem?

Comment: @s_vishnu Yes. I get 9.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just because you gave an initializer with 6 characters, doesn't mean those characters are actually stored anywhere for those small arrays.

Excess initializers are discarded. Which if you don't know what you are doing can come back and make your program ill-formed.

Let's consider the case where `a` has room for two characters. The compiler knows this, so it initializes it like this:

```
| 'H' | 'e' |
```

That's it. And while it's a perfectly valid character array, it's not a valid C-string. Because the array is not `\0` terminated. Once you feed this array to a library function that expects a C-string, you aren't guaranteed anything. It makes the behavior of your entire program **undefined**.

But practically speaking, `strlen` will just access memory which is beyond the bound of the array you defined. No telling what it can find there, or even if it will **ever** find a `\0` and return.

Comment: There is no mention that excess initializers are discarded in the standard, thus I believe it is UB by omission

Comment: There's only a mention what will happen if there are fewer elements: http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.9p21

Comment: @AnttiHaapala - ["Otherwise, only enough initializers from the list are taken to account for the elements or members of the subaggregate or the first member of the contained union"](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.9p20). It's a fairly convoluted way of describing it, but there isn't a compiler today that behaves otherwise.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala, sure there is, this is a constraint violation, a compiler **must** print a diagnostic.  The text in the standard is  *No initializer shall attempt to provide a value for an object not contained within the entity being
initialized.*

Answer (score 3):

It is **undefined behaviour** because `strlen(a)` could read beyond the size of `a` and cause undefined behavior (such as a crash). It means anything can happen.

`strlen` only works if a null terminator '\0' is present in the array of characters. If not present then the program behaviour is **undefined**.

**C11 - 7.23.6.3 The strlen function:**

> The **strlen** function returns the number of characters that precede
>   the terminating null character.

Comment: I don't think this is accessing out of bounds. I think it is passing a non null-terminated string to `strlen`.

Comment: `char a[3] = {'H','E','L','L','O','\0'};` would only initialize the first three characters in `a`, and hence it would not be a string, causing a UB with `strlen`.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya Thank you very much. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a partial assembly listing of this program compiled with gcc version 4.8.5 without any optimizations.

```
        .cfi_startproc
        pushq   %rbp
        .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
        .cfi_offset 6, -16
        movq    %rsp, %rbp
        .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
        subq    $16, %rsp
        movb    $72, -16(%rbp)
        movb    $69, -15(%rbp)
        movb    $76, -14(%rbp)
        leaq    -16(%rbp), %rax
        movq    %rax, %rdi
        call    strlen
```

You could see that the array `a` is allocated on the stack at offset of 0x16 from the base of the stack. Only the letters `HEL` are put on the stack. When strlen is being called it looks at the memory starting at rbp-16 until the first `0` byte is being encountered. The way the stack is initialized is such that this 0 byte is encountered at position rbp-10 leading, so your program prints

```
Length is 6
```